# Associate and save value in webform from VBA (visual basic for apps)

Tags: javascript, vba, excel

I'm writting a test code in Javascript on top of the VBA to autofill the spaces of a web form.

The problem is that, I've a searchbox of all contries with their acronym and I can't select the right one in the test.

For example:

```
.getElementById("DE_MAN_16").Value = "PT" (or 
.getElementById("DE_MAN_16").Value = Range("J21"))

.getElementById("DE_MAN_16").Click

.getElementById("DE_MAN_16").Select
```

- `DE_MAN_16` is the id of the country field. `J21` is the cell in excel where the value `PT` is stored.
- The value `PT` is not saved and the field remains empty.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: stop the code right after the first line.  does the "PT" show up on the web page?

Comment: Yes, but it's not saving the value, but I mange to fix the problem by adding setAttribute("theIdneeded").Value = Range("the cell I want")